# Converting sql via Laravel Query Build

Tags: sql, laravel

I would like to convert the following sql statement into a Laravel Query Build:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  view_orderline_manifest_data 
where 
  OrderID = 7 
  and (
    ProdCategoryParentID != 4 
    or ProdCategoryParentID IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Tried the following:

```
$orderlinedata=DB::table('view_orderline_data')
       ->select('ProdName','ProdID')->where('CustID',$CustID)
       ->where('OrderID',$OrderID)
       ->where('ProdCategoryParentID','!=' , 4)
       ->orWhereNull('ProdCategoryParentID')
       ->pluck('ProdName','ProdID')->all();
```

The problem is the following is being executed:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  view_orderline_manifest_data 
where 
  OrderID = 7 
  and ProdCategoryParentID != 4 
  or ProdCategoryParentID IS NOT NULL
```

essentially the brackets () are not being applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you desire, you'd need to pass a closure to the second `where` in your code.

```php
$orderlinedata=DB::table('view_orderline_data')
       ->select('ProdName','ProdID')->where('CustID',$CustID)
       ->where('OrderID',$OrderID)
       ->where(function ($query) {
           $query->where('ProdCategoryParentID','!=' , 4)
                 ->orWhereNull('ProdCategoryParentID');
       })
       ->pluck('ProdName','ProdID')->all();
```

[Laravel documentation on Parameter Grouping with the query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderlinedata = ViewOrderlineData::where('CustID',$CustID)
                                  ->where('OrderID', $OrderID)
                                  ->where(function ($query){
                                          $query->where('ProdCategoryParentID', '!=', 4)
                                                  ->orWhereNull('ProdCategoryParentID');
                                      })->pluck('ProdName','ProdID');
```